# How to remove current part from php file in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have project for upload files on server, but I want to save them in php file ...
thats okay.. But when I want to delete them from the array with `str_replace()` It`s not happen...
from this array:

```
$files = array(

'2920525' => array(
  'name' => 'Penguins',
  'size' => '759.6 KB',
  'unzip2920525' => NULL,
  'pass2920525' => NULL,
  'share2920525' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/99865723_Penguins.jpg',
),

'2683777' => array(
  'name' => 'Lighthouse',
  'size' => '548.1 KB',
  'unzip2683777' => NULL,
  'pass2683777' => NULL,
  'share2683777' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/68670654_Lighthouse.jpg',
),

'6456807' => array(
  'name' => 'Lighthouse - Копие - Копие',
  'size' => '548.1 KB',
  'unzip6456807' => NULL,
  'pass6456807' => NULL,
  'share6456807' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/94653321_Lighthouse---opie---opie.jpg',
),

'2363848' => array(
  'name' => 'Koala',
  'size' => '762.5 KB',
  'unzip2363848' => NULL,
  'pass2363848' => NULL,
  'share2363848' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/15704345_Koala.jpg',
),

'6172497' => array(
  'name' => 'Lighthouse',
  'size' => '548.1 KB',
  'unzip6172497' => NULL,
  'pass6172497' => NULL,
  'share6172497' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/53317261_Lighthouse.jpg',
),

);
```

I want to remove:

```
'6456807' => array(
  'name' => 'Lighthouse - Копие - Копие',
  'size' => '548.1 KB',
  'unzip6456807' => NULL,
  'pass6456807' => NULL,
  'share6456807' => NULL,
  'path' => 'uploads/anton_markov/94653321_Lighthouse---opie---opie.jpg',
),
```

I try with `str_replace()`,`preg_replace()` But nothing happen. I dont know why. When I remove the value from the array I want to save it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
unset($files['6456807']);
```

Comment: It is not happen because I want to save the file with the changed array